# Linux bash SORT by last name in email address

Tags: bash, sorting

Trying to find a way (one-liner command) to sort a text file with 1500+ email addresses by the last name in the actual address. but the last name could be 2nd or the 3rd field and always before the @. for example:

```
b.ggggg@domain.com
c.aaaaa@domain.com
r.b.kkkkk@domain.com
e.z.ddddd@domain.com
g.ccccc@domain.com
l.ttttt@domain.com
```

should sort to

```
c.aaaaa@domain.com
g.ccccc@domain.com
e.z.ddddd@domain.com
b.ggggg@domain.com
r.b.kkkkk@domain.com
l.ttttt@domain.com
```

I'm using `cat list.txt | sort -t . -k2` but I know it's wrong. thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Use `sed` or `awk` to add an extra field in a consistent place containing the last name, then sort by that field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the last name into its own field, sort by that field, then remove it.

```
sed 's/.*\.\([^.]*\)@/\1 &/' input.txt | sort -k 1,1 | cut -d' ' -f2- > output.txt
```

`sed` copies the last name to a field at the beginning of the line. `sort` sorts by the first field. Then `cut` removes the first field.

Comment: Btw.: The idea is called [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer

```
$ cat emails.txt | sed -E 's/@/D@/' | sed -E 's/\.([a-z]+D@)/\.D\1/' | sort -tD -k2,2 | tr -d 'D'
c.aaaaa@domain.com
g.ccccc@domain.com
e.z.ddddd@domain.com
b.ggggg@domain.com
r.b.kkkkk@domain.com
l.ttttt@domain.com
```